# React ASP.NET Core - js 'type assertion expressions' can only be used in a .ts file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core

I've just created a new React application in Visual Studio 2017 (not VSCode as a lot of the other posts on this error seem to be using) and it's set the default file contents of:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "React",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { FetchData } from './components/FetchData';
import { Counter } from './components/Counter';

export default class App extends Component {
  displayName = App.name

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/counter' component={Counter} />
            <Route path='/fetchdata' component={FetchData} />
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm trying to follow a tutorial to add a new component but when I add the following component it complains with an error message of "(JS) 'type assertion expressions' can only be used in a .ts file":

[image: Error Message]

I've found quite a few other posts which say to add the following code but I've added this to the appsettings.json file and that hasn't had any effect:

```
"javascript.validate.enable": false
```

Most posts around this subject seem to be using VSCode as well so not sure if this makes a difference that I'm on VS2017? Any ideas on what I need to alter to allow this to compile and run?

Comment: Read the error, you need to remove the type assertion expression. I.e. instead of `.then(response => response.json() as Promise<EmployeeData[]>)` do `.then(response => response.json())`.

Comment: And what about the 2 other errors that are highlighted in the image, what would they be changed to? I'm not sure why I should need to change the code from a tutorial (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51632.asp-net-core-2-0-crud-with-react-js-and-entity-framework-core.aspx) as that would defeat it's intended purpose. Surely it's more a configuration issue with my project rather than the actual coding?

Comment: You are following a tutorial for a React+TypeScript application but the project you created through visual studio is React only. That is why you are getting errors on TypeScript related things. Or perhaps you misclicked the menu item in the Create New File menu.

Comment: Ah I could well have chosen the wrong type from the menu, thanks I'll check that out.